# Is it possible to rotate one side of CubeTexture in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new in `three.js`, so I ask you for advice.

I use `CubeTexture` as `envMap` for my materials to make my objects looks like steel.

```
loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
this.cubeTexture = loader.load([
  posXUrl, negXUrl,
  posYUrl, negYUrl,
  posZUrl, negZUrl
]);
...
mesh.material.envMap = this.textureCube;
```

And everything is ok with it but I want to make one enhancement in my scene.

 The thing is that  floor (`negYUrl`) on `CubeTexture` is static, but my scene assumes that floor is rotated. Unfortunately didn't find any `API` that allow to rotate buttom side of `TextureCube` instance. 

Could you help me and point me on techniques that allow to do such things?

Comment: Sorry your question is slightly confusing... Could you share some code on how you did this? Can't you rotate your texture image itself for the floor side of the cube? If you just want to rotate this, you might want to learn about `uv`s (basically, `uv` is `xy` position for your image (that is considered to be `1x1` in size) based on where your vectors are)...

Comment: I am not sure what the relationship with the floor is, but this seems like you should just rotate the `negYUrl` image to the position you want? If you want to move this side of the cube separately, you will have to make it an individual plane mesh and maybe attach it to the cube mesh as a child and position it... (or rotate the vertices, but that is computationally worse and I think three does not like geometries to be changed after initialising a mesh)